existence of a smooth curve, not crossing certain surface
I'm solving a certain problem which could be brought to the following mathematical formulation:
how to find if there exist a smooth curve between two points (with given coordinates) which does not cross a certain surface (again, defined with a given equation f(x1, x2, ... xN)=0)?
I suspect that it could be related to orientable surfaces but do not know where to dig exactly, so any advice / textbooks / papers will be appreciated.
Also, it could be that the answer is different in different dimensions - like, it exist for two-dimensional space but does not for generic - I'm interested in all cases - starting from two dimensions and any higher.
Thank you in advance!

Do you think to a "single piece" surface, i.e., with a single connected component ? If yes, a necessary condition is that the two points are on the same size of the surface, which is easily done by testing if $f(x_1^1,...x_N^1)$ and  $f(x_1^2,...x_N^2)$ have the same sign. Do you agree with this basic condition (that you don't mention) ?
